# open ucbrowser from my app in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, uri

How can i open any other application from my application like open ucbrowser from my **wp8**   app.
I think uri schemes works but i don't know how to implement that in c#.  I want ucbrowser uri
whatsapp uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only navigate to the uri scheme if the application has registered it.

The relevant article is here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Here are the default app uri schemes:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Apps that have exposed and registered for a uri scheme should note it in this page here:

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List

You call the uri like so, if it is available.

```
var uriSchemeString = AppuriScheme;
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uriSchemeString));
```

Comment: thanxxx there is any idea for set patternlock in my aaplication??

Comment: since that's a different question i would advise that you ask in a new thread. also you need to give more context as to what you've tried and what you're actually trying to do when asking questions.

Comment: I want to add pattern lock to my app like password validation 
it is a link for that but i cant understand  

http://nishantcop.blogspot.in/2014/02/pattern-lock-for-windows-phone.html

any other idea??